# Is "FDisk+HFormat" or "Disc Cleaning+HFormat" = LowFormat？

Tags: format, disc

Just feeling very curious about the two things：

1) FDisk+HFormat.

2) Disc Cleaning (by writing each space with random byte or "0" or "FF", such us what we do in Windows for using "cipher /w (Your Disc). + HFormat.

In my mind, LFormat will seperate your whole disc by checking each space is phycially bad or not, and do some other checkings.

However now we can use "ScanDisc", "chk" or HFormat, Disc Cleaning releated commands to do almost what LFormat does... So I wanna know:

a) Does a "Full HFormat" clean all the data in the DATA range of your hard disc, as well as your FAT, based on seperated tracks from the disc factories?

b) Compared with a, is a "LFormat" rearranging all the tracks of a hard disc and do seperations of sections?

c) LFormat and a full HFormat will both check sections whether they are bad or not……So what're the differences between them？ Is the former for physically checking and the latter one for "logically checking"?

Reguards!

Comment: No such thing as a low level format in modern hard drives. Any full format can be considered 'low' and writing 0/1s over that is another matter called disk wipe.

Comment: @Overmind：Are you sure？As far as I see, it seems that a full HFormat will logically clean all the data in the sections based on the orignal seperated tracks from factories. However for a LFormat, it will rearrange the track and seperate the sections……But I'm not sure about the accurate differences.

Comment: Yes, I have added that to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as a low level format in modern hard drives. Any full format can be considered 'low' and writing 0/1s over that is another matter called disk wipe.

Something like true low level format was valid long time ago in the MFM hard drives era. Not anymore. There is no more higher magnetic setting than the default one because of density reasons. There is no space to re-arrange anything either. Today, formatting the drive and zeroing it is sometimes called low level format, but it has absolutely nothing to do with that. Zero-fill or random fill after a format is not in any way a low level format.

Low and high level format is now-days used to distinguish between zero-fill, which returns the drive to the state it left the factory from a data content perspective, and the operating system's (normal) file system format, which may or may not change the actual data content of the drive (usually not, since it's usually a quick format).

Comment: But you see that LFormat will also seperate sections, tracks……ect. And HFormat won't, it will clean data based on seperated sections, tracks in physical……？

Comment: No it will not. No software has the possibility to do that. Last thing that could alter something like tracks was the 2M FD formatter from the MS-DOS era.